# Can't figure out a solution to 'The model backing the 'TasksJobsDbContext' context has changed since the database was created'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've been trying to solve this issue for 3 days now, and just can't figure it out. I've searched the web a lot and most of the solutions suggest using null initializer which doesn't solve my problem:

This is my model:

```
public class JobsRecord
{
    [Key] 
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public int TaskID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskID")]
    public virtual TasksRecord Task { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public Int64 DeviceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime NextRunTimestamp { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeOfRun { get; set; }

    public TasksJobsMisc.RunResultEnum RunResult { get; set; }

    public int JobResult { get; set; }

    public double JobResultValue { get; set; }

    public string ExtendedResults { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class JobsRecordHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public int TaskID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskID")]
    public virtual TasksRecord Task { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public Int64 DeviceID { get; set; }

    public TasksJobsMisc.RunResultEnum RunResult { get; set; }

    public int JobResult { get; set; }

    public double JobResultValue { get; set; }

    public string ExtendedResults { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class TasksRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Interval { get; set; } //minutes

    [Required]
    public string TaskObjName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public ReporterType Type { get; set; }

    public int MaxDaysSinceLastReport { get; set; }

    public int MinVersion { get; set; }

    public int MaxVersion { get; set; }

    public int FailureInterval { get; set; } //minutes

    public string Site { get; set; }

    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    public string JSONConfig { get; set; } //extra configuration

    public int ParallelLevel { get; set; } //control parallelism for each task

    public int EnableDisable { get; set; }
}``
```

What I'm trying to do is to add the last field, EnableDisable, to the TaskRecord class. Up until now I worked with EF Code First migrations and was pretty happy about it, but now, when I try to add the EnableDisable field to that class and run 'Add-Migration TasksEnable' and then Update-Database, although it runs successfully, When I run my code I get the 'The model backing the 'TasksJobsDbContext' context has changed since the database was created' error where I use my context for the first time:

```
using (var db = new TasksJobsDbContext())
            {
                var blankjobs = db.JobsRecords.Include("Task").Where(x => x.RunResult == TasksJobsMisc.RunResultEnum.Blank);
                Log.DebugFormat("Found {0} jobs", blankjobs.Count());
                jobs = blankjobs.Where(x => DateTime.Now.CompareTo(x.NextRunTimestamp) > 0).ToList();
            }
```

I know I can 'restart' the migrations like I read in some other stackoverflow thread, by dropping the migrations table and directory and just start from scratch and let the database and the migrations be recreated, but obviously I don't want to lose my data and more important, I want to figure it out so that I can handle it in the future.

I tried the null initializer and it didn't help.

Every time I get this error I just revert the last migration by 'Update-Database -TargetMigration: 'my last working migration'' and that fixes the problem.

I tried some debugging to add some more data:

```
using (var db = new TasksJobsDbContext())
            {
                Log.DebugFormat("compatible (with metadata): {0}", db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true));
                Log.DebugFormat("compatible: {0}", db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false));
                Log.DebugFormat("exists: {0}", db.Database.Exists());
                db.Database.Initialize(true);}
```

What I get is (initializer set do             Database.SetInitializer(null);
 or to Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());, same results for both)
: false, false, true, then this exception again...

I'm using VS2013, EF 6.9.6.0, Code First, MySQL, and this is my first project with EF (went pretty well up until now).

Comment: So just before you use the context, have you checked that the database correctly represents your POCO classes?

Comment: @Ruskin Good point, yes I did. went over the database and checked each column, checked that last column was added as expected, I don't see any mismatch between my class and the db

Comment: Try to run `Add-migration` one more time and check if it's empty.

Comment: Can you show me the code of your database initializer logic?  Also, does it happen after every change you make to your code first entities or just that one new property?

Comment: @Vladislav, did it, it's empty (the up and down functions)

Comment: @Ruskin, that bug never happened before, and I have working migrations for that specific table, everything was OK. now, I can't change ANYTHING in any of my tables in that database. any change to the entities cause the same error.
And regarding the initialize: I don't have a custom initializer. just calling CreateDatabaseIfNotExists or Database.SetInitializer<TasksJobsDbContext>(null). Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Also check that `connectionString` for running app is the same as for migrations.

Comment: @Vladislav you mean run "Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "TasksJobsDbContext"" ? specifying the connection string while updating? Did it, didn't work, still get the same error

Comment: @Alonzzo2 I've just got stuck some time ago, running migrations on local db, while starting application on dev one.  :) 

Is last entry in `MigrationHistory` table equal to your last migration?

Comment: @Vladislav this is the last migrationid from the migration table: 201508021343079_TasksEnableDisable
So I guess the answer is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we've found in comments everything seems ok, except the error itself.. 
I can't guess the actual reason of it, but have some proposals to mitigate the outcome.

- Generate scripts for all the data you have (SQL management studio has such possibility, for example), delete your db, run all the migrations for db creation, restore data and work like this never happened (actually I've never met such a weird behaviour before, so with high probability it will not repeat)
- Delete your `MigrationHistory` table and all the migrations (code and resources), then create migration starting from actual db state with use of `-IgnoreChanges` flag for `add-migration` command.

As written in docs for `-IgnoreChanges`.

> Scaffolds an empty migration ignoring any pending changes detected in the current model.  This can be used to create an
>   initial, empty migration to enable Migrations for an existing
>   database. N.B.  Doing this assumes that the target database schema is
>   compatible with the current model.

But with this approach you won't be able to recreate your db on another server using migrations only.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd suggestion: 
a. No data will be lost, right? just to make sure
b. What if when going to production I will generate an SQL script to build my new database? Will I still be able to continue using EF CF migrations with the new database?

Comment: a) You will delete `MigrationHistory` table and create an empty migration, so there is no possibility to lost any data (make a backup nevertheless).
b) You won't be able to recreate db by running migrations only, your current db state will be ignored by migrations, only further changes will be tracked (I've forgot to mention, you should delete all your current migrations (classes and resources) as well). But you will be able to recreate db, with use of Management Studio or any other utility, which generates db creation scripts. And migrations should work on new db as well.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav, what you suggested fixed my problem: just recreated migration (after deleting the previous migrations and migration table) with the -ignorechanges flag, while hoping this won't happen again:)